Rouding a decimal to two decimals gives a wrong result?
I have this number in a decimal: 606.60499999999999999999999999 and I need to round it to two decimals. The correct answer is 606.61, but C# gives me 606.60...
From Visual Studio:

How can I get Math.Round(aDecimal, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) to return 606.61?

Your number is lower than the midpoint.
It's not 606.6049999999 -> 606.605 -> 606.61

Can you explain why you expect it to be 606.61?

Why do you think a value which is less than 606.605 should be rounded to 606.61 ?

The correct answer is 606.61
Why  and how?

Possible Duplicate?

@Sweeper ... here in Denamrk (financials) if I round 606.60499999999999999999999999 to three decimal, it will be 606.605 and round it to two deecimal is 606.61 ... if you put the number 606.60499999999999999999999999 in Excel and ask it to round to two decimal, you will get 606.61.

How did you ask Excel to round it? When I format that number with 2 decimals in Excel, I get 606.60 not 6060.61. Also when I type in the formula =ROUND(606.60499999999999999999999999, 2) it displays as 606.60

@MojoDK Then you have to do this in two separate steps also here, ie first round to three decimal places and then round the result to two decimal places... And I don't know what version of Excel you have, when I round your value to 2 places I get 606.60

As mentioned above you can round in 2 steps (to 3 decimal places and then to 2), like this: decimal.Round(decimal.Round(aDecimal, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);.

double is binary fraction with limited precision; in your case 606.6049999999999 == 5335754007736484 / 2^43 == 606.60500000000001818989403545856475830078125

Short answer: You can't, because that would be incorrect.
The difference between your two shown cases from the VS debugger is: Your first value is a decimal type, your second is a double.
A double has a precision of about 17 places, so actually there is some kind of rounding/inprecision happening before and what goes into Math.Round(606.60499999999999999999999999, ...) isn't that exact value but probably something like 606.605...... And that of course is rounded to 606.61.
But the error is in not the rounding of the decimal value, but in the rounding of the double value. Read also Is floating-point math broken? on this topic.
The semantics of rounding to n decimals is pretty clear: Look at (only!) the n+1 decimal digit. In your case with n == 2 that's 4 -- which is not the midpoint -- and therefore the result is towards zero.
If you need the behaviour your mentioned in the comments, you have to do this in two separate steps. Ie, round to 3 decimals first which will give you 606.605. And then round that intermediate result to 2 decimals, which will give you your desired result of 606.61
